# How to implement multiple API in one component

Tags: json, reactjs, api, jsonplaceholder

i stuck in a project where i have to implement [JSON Place Holder Post API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) and [JSON Place Holder Comment API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments) both API in a particular component.Actually my task is build a project like a facebook post component where user can post and comment. I implemented Post API successfully but i couldn't find any solution to use comment API. I did all thing but it's not show in my Home component.
How can i implement comment api in my home component

[image: This is my home component where i try to implement post and comment API]

**my console said it present but i couldn't show this**
[image: my console said it present but i couldn't show this]
**This is Home.js File**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import Comment from '../Comment/Comment';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
const [post,setPost] = useState([]);
const [comment,setComment] = useState([]);


useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>setPost(data))

},[])

useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>setComment(data))
},[])

return (
    <div>
        
        
        <div>
        {
            post.map(post=><Post post={post}></Post>)
            
        }
         
        </div>
       <div className="main-body">
       {
                comment.map(comment=><Comment comment={comment}></Comment>)
            }

       </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default Home;
```

**This comment.js File**

```
import React from 'react';

const Comment = (props) => {
const {name,email} = props.comment.name;
console.log(props.comment);
return (
    <div>
          {name}
          {email}
    </div>
);
};

export default Comment;
```

**This is post.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Post.css';

const Post = (props) => {

const {title,body} = props.post;
return (
    <div className="body-style">
        <h1 className="name">{title}</h1>
        <p>{body}</p>
    </div>
);
 };

export default Post;
```

***Please help me I need solution***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is incorrect, in order to do that, comment should be children of post, and home will pass data to the post. Since you fetch data from 2 difference API, you need to combined it into 1 source and pass that down.

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
const [post,setPost] = useState([]);
const [comment,setComment] = useState([]);
const [ info, setInfo ] = useState([]);


useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>setPost(data))

},[])

useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>setComment(data))
},[])

//Function to combine post and comment base on ID
const merge = (post, comment) => {
                const temp = [];
                post.forEach((x) => {
                    comment.forEach((y) => {
                        if (x.id === y.id) {
                            let cName = y.name;
                            let cEmail = y.email;
                            let cBody = y.body;
                            temp.push({ ...x, cName, cEmail, cBody });
                        }
                    });
                });
                return temp;
            };
      
useEffect(
        () => {     
            setInfo(merge(post, comment));
            console.log(info);
        },
        [ post, comment ]
    );
return (
    <div>
        {info.map((each) => <Post key={each.id} data={each} />)}
    </div>
);
};

export default Home;
```

**Post.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Comment from './Comment';

const Post = (props) => {
    const { title, body, cEmail, cName } = props.data;
    return (
        <div className="body-style">
            <h1 className="name">{title}</h1>
            <p>{body}</p>
            <Comment email={cEmail} name={cName} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Post;
```

**Comment.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Comment = ({ name, email }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {name}
            {email}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Comment;
```

Comment: Nothing change there it again missing comment api

Comment: Are you sure, I just checked, it works perfectly

Comment: are u understand my question i try to implement two api in one component but comment api doesn't work accurately. i used const {name,email} = props.comment but nothing change just show post api

Comment: Oh, so you want each comment right below each post? If so you approach completely wrong, it doesn't work like that. <br>The comment component should be the chilren of the post component and the home will pass data to the post.

Comment: can you help me to do this actually i am totally new

Comment: Keep in mind that it works but not recommended because it is slow and not optimized. In the future, you want to make your own API that included both posts and comments. Also fetching everything at once is redundant, try fetching chunks by chunks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229711/discussion-between-lazy-coder-and-co-pham).